# phpmailer gives HTTP ERROR 500 when i try to test email on cloudways

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer, cloudways

I am a newbie in web development. I wrote a php code to send emails from a form and i hosted it in cloudways. I get a HTTP ERROR 500 whenever i hit the submit button.

```
    <?php

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    # code...
      $name = trim($_POST["fullname"]);
      $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
      $phone_no = trim($_POST["phone_num"]);
      $partner_type = $_POST["Partner_type"];

     if ($name == "" || $email == "" || $phone_no == " ") {
        echo "please fill the required fields name , email , phone number";
      }

      if ($_POST["adds"] != "") {
        echo "Bad form input";
        exit;
      }

      require 'class.phpmailer.php';

      $mail = new PHPMailer();

      if (!$mail->ValidateAddress($email)) {
        # code...
        echo "Invalid Email Address";
        exit;
      }


      $email_body = "";
      $email_body .= "Name " . $name . "\n";
      $email_body .= "Email " . $email . "\n";
      $email_body  .= "Phone Number " . $phone_no . "\n";
      $email_body .= "Partner Type " . $partner_type . "\n";


      $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
      $mail->addAddress('rescuetl@localhost', 'gbubemi');     // Add a recipient

    /**$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
      $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
      **/

      $mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML

      $mail->Subject = 'Become a Partner ' . $name ;
      $mail->Body    = $email_body;
      $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

      if(!$mail->send()) {
          echo 'Message could not be sent.';
          echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
          exit;
      } else {
          echo 'Message has been sent';
      }

    header("location:index.php?status=thanks");
}

 ?>
```

please it is really frustrating i need help. Thanks.

Comment: Check your PHP error logs.

Comment: ...and please sign up at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - your code is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to debug the application weather email is sending or not or may be it's stuck in a queue. you can check it by running "mailq" on terminal. Next first try to send simple email on Cloudways like this:

```
<?php 
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; //PHPMailer Object 
$mail = new PHPMailer; //From email address and name 
$mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com"; 
$mail->FromName = "Full Name"; //To address and name 
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com", "Recepient Name");//Recipient name is optional
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com"); //Address to which recipient will reply 
$mail->addReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply"); //CC and BCC 
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com"); 
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com"); //Send HTML or Plain Text email 
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = "Subject Text"; 
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content"; 
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} 
else { echo "Message has been sent successfully"; 
}
if(!$mail->send()) 
{ 
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "Message has been sent successfully"; 
}
```

If it works and email sent then try sending by applying smtp credentials like this:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Enable SMTP debugging.

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                           

//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.

$mail->isSMTP();        

//Set SMTP host name                      

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                      

//Provide username and password

$mail->Username = "name@gmail.com";             

$mail->Password = "super_secret_password";                       

//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                       

//Set TCP port to connect to

$mail->Port = 587;                    

$mail->From = "name@gmail.com";

$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

$mail->addAddress("name@example.com", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";

$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";

$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send())

{

echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}

else

{

echo "Message has been sent successfully";

}
?>
```

You can also set up Smtp on Cloudways Platform in server settings:
[image: SMTP settings for cloudways]

Read the full article here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/send-emails-in-php-using-phpmailer/

Comment: @gbubemismith glad it work for you. mark it as correct answer plz :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function PHPMailerAutoload which is in the package .. it is simple and works very well. I use it myself on a project. And in addition, it is very easy to assimilate.

```
function sendMail($destinaire, $code, $prename){

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$userMail = $destinataire;  //Recipient
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->isSMTP();
$success_send = " Le code de reservation a éte envoyé à ".$userMail;
$failed_send = "Echec: le mail in not send verifier votre email";
//On ouvre l'authentification
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Les creditentials
$mail->Username = "Sender@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "Senderpass"; 
//set the type of protection
$mail->SMTPSecure ="ssl"; //tls
//Definissons un port
$mail->Port ="465"; //587 pour tls
//L'objet du message
$mail->Subject ="Reservation enregistré";
//Le message en lui meme, afin le contenu quoi
$mail->Body ="Bonjour '.$prename.' Nous avons enregistré votre reservation. 
Veuillez presenter le Code suivant le jour du voyage ".$code;

//Bref, qui envoi?
$mail->setFrom('sender@gmail.com', 'Indiza - Travel Dimension');
//set where we are sending this email(à qui)
$mail->addAddress($userMail);
//Envoyer l'email

if($mail->send())
    return $success_send;
else
    return $failed_send;        
}
```

**Utility**

To start (if you use Gmail) you should lower the security level of the account that sends the messages

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

[Github Php Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

And if is necessary, This link will be very useful [Codingpassive/PHPMailer](http://codingpassiveincome.com/phpmailer-tutorial)

Just call a function like this

```
$idz = sendMail("$receiverMail","anyCode","receiverName");
```

**Is it really computer? No gentleman, we do crafts.**

**Est-ce réellement de l'informatique? Non mon ami, on fait juste du bricolage.**